# Cisco ASA access-lists redundant entries

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, access-control-list

I need to modify existing configuration of the CISCO ASA. While analyzing the configuration I noticed something that looks redundant to me. I would like to see if somebody can confirm my doubts.

```
access-list LANA_access_in extended permit ip any any log debugging inactive
access-list LANA_access_in extended permit icmp any any log debugging inactive
access-list LANA_access_in extended permit icmp 172.12.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.5.83.0 255.255.255.0
access-list LANA_access_in extended permit ip 172.12.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.5.83.0 255.255.255.0
...
access-group LANA_access_in in interface LAN_A_Lan
```

Am I right that after the first two lines, second two lines are completely redundant?

And to make things even better there is this part of config

```
access-list global_access extended permit ip any any log debugging inactive
access-list global_access extended permit icmp any any log debugging inactive
...
access-group global_access global
```

If I understand correctly, this will allow all ingress traffic on all ports, and previously mentioned two specific lines are "double" redundant.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: No, you're incorrect.  You seem to be ignoring where it says `inactive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. The `inactive` keyword means just what it says: the entry in question is inactive, disabled, not in use, ignored by the packet processing.

The purpose of these two lines is to have something in place for a quick investigation. If an administrator feels the need to trace all packets through that ACL she can just remove the `inactive` attribute from the first `access-list` entry and the ASA will permit and log all arriving IP packets. When the investigation is complete she will put the `inactive` back in and the original ruleset will be in effect again.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was assuming that inactive refers to debugging, but it actually disables the whole ACL line.